# Could not write to TensorArray index because the value shape is incompatible with the TensorArray's inferred element shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a string Tensor (named **sentence**) where I want to get the embeddings for its words:

```
sentence = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.string_split([x], delimiter=' ').values, sentence, dtype=tf.string)
```

I use the above code to apply a string split on all sentences in the batch. I then apply a lookup in my word table to obtain the word indexes for each of the words inside these Tensors:

```
sentence = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.cast(word_table.lookup(x), tf.int32), sentence, dtype=tf.int32)
```

When running with **batch size** of **1**, I have no problems running the code. However, with batch sizes bigger than 1, I always get the following error which points to the first code snippet above.

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): TensorArray sentence_splitter/map/TensorArray_1_1: Could not write to TensorArray index 10 because the value shape is [4] which is incompatible with the TensorArray's inferred element shape: [6] (consider setting infer_shape=False).

I don't understand what Tensorflow is trying to say with this error! It would be great if someone can explain this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When your batch size is bigger than 1, after this code

```
sentence = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.string_split([x], delimiter=' ').values, sentence, dtype=tf.string)
```

tf.string_split() function on different sentences, produces different number of splited results. The incompatible of each dimension makes the final result can't be stored into tensor, so error occurs. Is this clear?